# How to separate controllers and services in fastify?

Tags: fastify

how to separate controllers and services in fastify, so as not to write all the basic business logic in controllers. I want the logic to be in separate classes or functions so that it can be reused and not tied to the framework. Maybe there are good examples on github, I couldn't find them myself, in all examples logic is written in controllers

Comment: Could you make an example?

Comment: I am also finding the same, but not finding anything fruitful. can anyone help in this regard?